# Add a hyperlink to paragraph using itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

I have a paragraph that I want to attach a link with, by doing the below it displays another text on the bottom instead of the link being attached to the existing text.

```
   Paragraph portfolioText = new Paragraph("View our Portfolio", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 15, Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.WHITE));
           portfolioText.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
  portfolioText.SetLeading(12.1f, 12.1f);
            portfolioText.IndentationLeft = 90;


            Anchor portAnch = new Anchor(portfolioText);
            portAnch.Reference = "http://portfolio.xxxxx.com/";
doc.Add(portfolioText);
doc.Add(portAnch);
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

UPDATE:

I tried with chunk instead like:

```
Chunk portText = new Chunk("View Portfolio");
            portText.SetAnchor(new Uri("http://portfolio.xxxxx.com/"));
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
            p.Add(portText);
            doc.Add(p);
```

and it worked but how do I apply all the font style/size and position just like the previous paragraph?

UPD 2

I tried to give it the styles like this but then I don't even see it on the page

```
 Chunk portText = new Chunk("View Portfolio");
            portText.SetAnchor(new Uri("http://portfolio.xxxx.com/"));
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
            p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            p.Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 15, Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.WHITE);
            p.SetLeading(12.1f, 12.1f);
            p.IndentationLeft = 90;
            p.Add(portText);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example code above has all the *individual* working parts to do what you want, just not *put together* the correct way. Here's a simple working example (using iTextSharp 5.5.12 like you are):

```
// [1] create a Chunk with font and colors you want
var anchor = new Chunk("View our Portfolio")
{
    Font = new Font(
        Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 25,
        Font.NORMAL,
        BaseColor.BLUE
    )
};

// [2] set the anchor URL
anchor.SetAnchor("http://portfolio.xxxxx.com/");

// [3] create a Paragraph with alignment, indentation, etc
Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
{
    Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
    IndentationLeft = 90
};
p.SetLeading(12.1f, 12.1f);

// [4] add chunk to Paragraph
p.Add(anchor);

// [5] add Paragraph to Document
document.Add(p);
```

Result PDF:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your question is straight from chapter 6 of the "building blocks" tutorial.

https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-6-creating-actions-destinations-and-bookmarks

example with named actions:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
.add("Go to last page")
.setAction(PdfAction.createNamed(PdfName.LastPage));
document.add(p);

p = new Paragraph()
.add("Go to first page")
.setAction(PdfAction.createNamed(PdfName.FirstPage));
document.add(p);
```

example with GoTo action:

```
new Paragraph()
    .addTabStops(tabstops)
    .add(entry.getKey())
    .add(new Tab())
    .add(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()))
    .setAction(PdfAction.createGoTo(
            PdfExplicitDestination.createFit(entry.getValue())));
```

Where `entry` is a an entry from `Map<String, Integer`

The working **iText7** code for your usecase is

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE));
Document layoutDocument = new Document(pdfDocument);

Paragraph portfolioText = new Paragraph("View our Portfolio");
portfolioText.setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont());
portfolioText.setFontColor(Color.ORANGE);
portfolioText.setFixedLeading(12.1f);
portfolioText.setFirstLineIndent(90f);
portfolioText.setAction(PdfAction.createURI("http://google.com/"));

layoutDocument.add(portfolioText);
layoutDocument.close();
```

Comment: can you put the change in my existing snippet? I tried with  `portfolioText.Add("http://portfolio.xxxxx.com/");` but it displays the link

Comment: Of course that happens. The `add` method on Paragraph is meant to add text. If you look at the example I gave you (and the examples I linked to) you'll see that I called the method `setAction`

Comment: I tried to add like `portfolioText.setAction`but there is no such method error is thrown

Comment: Which version of iText are you using?

Comment: I am using iTextsharp 5.5.12.0

Comment: I updated the code to work with iText7.
If you're using iText5, you will need to look at the documentation yourself.
For new projects however, we recommend you switch to iText7. It's newer, and loads more bugfixes have been done.

Comment: Like I said, this works with iText7. iText7 is not the same as iText5. Specifically I am using itext 7.0.5

Comment: For extra questions, ask another question on StackOverflow. It makes it easier for future visitors of StackOverflow to be able to find the answer they are looking for under the matching question.